# HTML multiple select storing in MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, select, data-structures

Is there any good solution for storing `HTML` multiple select filed in one `MySQL` field?

I was tried use a MySQL table with 5 columns for one `<select>` with 5 options, but this is not so comfortable with 40-50 select boxes, or for example a multiple country selector.

```
<select id="country" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">USA</option>
   <option value="2">Canada</option>
   <option value="3">Peru</option>
   ...
</select>
```

In MySQL query I want to use multiple values too, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE country IN (1,5,20,55);
```

Is there something datastructure or data type... or something to store this searchable?

Comment: something like select2? http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: have you heard about many-to-many relationships?

Comment: no... I have a big form in html with 146 questions, all multiple select type. How can I store this in MySQL most simple? String data type is not too good because of the data table has 100.000+ records. It will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a query column for each user that simply stores the Where In string.
Then you can get that string

```
SELECT string FROM users WHERE id = userid
variable = queryresults;

SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE country IN (variable);
```